# Change the default find-grep command in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, fish

When I execute `find-grep` command in emacs, I got `find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  {} +`, since I'm using fish shell as the default shell, to make this command work I have to execute `find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  \{\} +`.

I tried to modify the emacs source code, below are my changes:

`/usr/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/ldefs-boot.el` line 12669: `` If `exec-plus' use `find -exec \{\} +'. ``

`/usr/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/loaddefs.el` line 12669: `` If `exec-plus' use `find -exec \{\} +'. ``

But it doesn't make any sense, when I execute `find-grep` still shows `find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  {} +`. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong or how should I figure out this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text you changed does not look like executable code.  Probably you just changed a doc string (actually, a bit of googling reveals that this is in the documentation string for [`grep-find-use-xargs`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/grep.el#n433)).  But Emacs is eminently customizable; all you have to do is to set the value of `grep-find-template` to something which is more suitable for you personally, in your own `.emacs/init.el` or similar.

```
(setq grep-find-template
      "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -nH -e <R> \\{\\} +")
```

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) for further documentation and, of course, the built-in documentation (<kbd>ctrl-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `grep-find-template` <kbd>RET</kbd>).

The actual source code is in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/grep.el#n174 but you really, really, *really* do not want to edit the source code. The user-level customizability without code changes is one of the foundational designs of Emacs. Learn to use this facility.

Comment: I was searching `grep-find` in emacs's source dir and found those 2 files match, so I tried to modify them. You answer helps a lot, and I found grep-find's definition in `/usr/share/emacs/24.4/lisp/progmodes/grep.el.gz`

Comment: No, don't modify the files. Just override what you need to override in your own personal init file. Any changes to the source will be lost with the next upgrade, and on a multi-user system, you are breaking things for everybody else.

Comment: i'd use `<D>`, not `.` _______ `grep-find-template`'s docstring says one should use all the place holders. e.g. mine is: `"find -L <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -nH -e <R> \\{\\} +"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command '("find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  \\{\\} +" . 34))
```

Will place the cursor on just slightly after the `-e`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the function `grep-apply-setting` to set the variable `grep-find-command`, and double up on the backslashes before the curly braces:

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command "find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  \\{\\} +")
```

Comment: can I set default cursor position to `-e  (here) \\{\\}`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the original value you can do something like this. It will find files no further down than two directory levels, that are not emacs backup files, and have been modified in the past week.

```lisp
(defun grep-find-newer-shallow ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((gfc grep-find-command))
    (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command '("find . -maxdepth 2 -type f ! -name '*#' -mtime -7 -exec grep -nH -e  \\{\\} +" . 69))
    (call-interactively 'grep-find)
    (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command gfc)))
```