# Change the default cursor position of find-grep command in emacs

Tags: bash, emacs

I changed default `find-grep` command 
(helped by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28915547/1897767)).

my init.el is following.

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command "find . -type d \\( -name '.git' \\) -prune -o -type f  -exec grep -nH -e  \\{\\} +")
```

and then I execute `find-grep`, I get minibuffer and cursor is at end of line.
I want to change default cursor position to after `-e`

```
find . -type d \( -name '.git' \) -prune -o -type f  -exec grep -nH -e (*here*) \{\} +
```

is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: It would be better, in my opinion, for an interactive request for the value of `*here*` before the minibuffer is populated with the find-grep command.  But, alas, that's not your question . . .  With that being said, it is certainly possible to `goto-char` in the minibuffer or `backward-char` or `re-search-backward "\\*here\\*" nil t`, etc. . . ., but I've not tried that before.

Comment: The documentation for `grep-template` documents a number of special formatting codes available to you in this context, but `grep-apply-setting` does not seem to have these options for `grep-find-command`.  The default value is a `cons` with apparently the value of point as the tail, but manually setting it to that value seems ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code in your `init.el` to the following:

```lisp
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command '("find . -type d \\( -name '.git' \\) -prune -o -type f  -exec grep -nH -e  \\{\\} +" . 72))
```